# how to duplicate pages in SharePoint

Tags: web-part, pages, duplicate

I am trying to copy page layout from one sub site to another. It contains web parts and also from the context menu this page layout contain duplicate options for creating multiple pages quickly (`mavention.sharepoint.duplicate.min.js`) I am using, but when I am copying to another site.

The whole web parts are coming as well as javascript file also loading but duplicate options is not coming.

Please help.